# Access O365 Modern Groups information from VSTO Outlook Add-in

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, office365, single-sign-on, vsto

I want to build an add-in for the MS Outlook 2019 desktop app (-> VSTO add-in). It is intended to gather some information from O365 Modern Groups that the current Outlook user (me) is a member of. As far as I understand the only way to achieve this is to use Microsoft Graph API because there is no support to access O365 related things via Outlook object model/Office Interop. Given that (and please correct me if I am wrong) I might use the *Microsoft.Graph* Nuget packages. With them I would like to call the following endpoint:

```
POST /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/getMemberGroups
```

possible in C# with this code snippet:

```
GraphServiceClient graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

var securityEnabledOnly = true;

await graphClient.Me
    .GetMemberGroups(securityEnabledOnly)
    .Request()
    .PostAsync();
```

My question is: Is there a way of using the existing Outlook credentials for the authProvider so that I don't need the user to enter credentials?
I read that web add-ins have the possibility to use different authentication flows including a SSO flow. But that does not fit for VSTO.

I thought of a *IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider*. But therefore I need to provide a clientId which I do not have. Does that ultimately mean that I need to register my add-in in some way? Can't I just write an add-in for my personal purposes without admin support?

```
IPublicClientApplication publicClientApplication = PublicClientApplicationBuilder
            .Create(clientId)
            .WithTenantId(tenantID)
            .Build();

IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider authProvider = new IntegratedWindowsAuthenticationProvider(publicClientApplication, scopes);
```

Comment: Why you want to use legacy Outlook VSTO addins? Rather i would suggest you to make use of Office.js and build Outlook addins. Here's the link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/apis

Comment: Using this also you can Authorize to Microsoft Graph with SSO as well. here's the doc - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/authorize-to-microsoft-graph

Comment: Hi Dev, thank you for your suggestion. But I'm stuck using a desktop client for a handful of reasons. :(

Comment: Being the legacy technology like VSTO might not have the native integrations with Graph API. Being said that still you can do so, technically you can make use of the HTTPClient (see if you can use Microsoft Graph SDK) as part of your implementation, but you may face issues when you try implementing SSO related stuff (hence recommended webaddins) So just sharing this on best effort basis for you to give a try. You get it started like here: "https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/active-directory-dotnetcore-console-up-v2/aad-username-password-graph/". Let me know how it goes.

Comment: You can follow the above sample, it has detailed steps. In order to access Microsoft Graph, first you need to register your app in Azure AD, get a token with proper scope/permission, so that you can use a protected resource like Microsoft Graph.